# How to run Red5 Server in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, red5

I have checked out the source code from Red5 SVN. And after right clicking "build.xml", I have downloaded many jars via Ivy. Finally Eclipse noticed my that: "BUILD SUCCESSFUL".

And also I have installed Red5 Plugin for Eclipse. Then how to run Red5 in Eclipse IDE?

Comment: how you install red5 plugin in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would not do that.
If you want to test some of your server side logic you can:

1. Use Spring Mock up to do JUnit tests (see AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests). That way you can load a Spring context, if your application uses Red5's Spring services.
2. You can use the Remote Debugging Console from inside Eclipse. To set that up, you would start Red5 with some special parameters and then connect Eclipse to it. We have published some documentation about setting up Red5 and Eclipse for that some time ago: http://code.google.com/p/openmeetings/wiki/DebugServer.
3. You can download for example the .war version and setup a regular Tomcat project in Eclipse and then deploy the .war as webapp into your Eclipse project. We have done that but we removed it again cause producing such a .war has some disadvantages and it is easier to upgrade to latest Red5 version if you run the standalone version.

However, I prefer using JUnit as it allows to rerun the test-case or for example integrate it into your Nightly/Daily/Continuous build environment.

Sebastian

Comment: how to set up developer environment in eclipse? just clues are enough because most of the tutorials are old and with latest versions none of those instructions are working. please help.

Answer (score 0):

May be Useful, Try!:

Red5 can be installed as stand alone server or as a war deployment.

The procedure is to create war deployment of red5 version 0.8(old version). (Lengthy, please bear with me).

Download and install jdk1.6, glassfish2.1 and netbeans 6.5 on linux.

Download "Red5War_0.8.0.war".

I am sharing in the hope that the following may help the community to create a deployable war red5 version 0.8 on glassfish2.1 by following the steps using in Netbeans 6.5:

Step 1: Un-Zip the Red5War_0.8.0.war

Step 2: Create a web project named "red5" in Netbeans

Step 3: Copy the content of "/WEB-INF/classes" of inflated war folder and paste it in "Source Packages" of Netbeans Project.

Step 4: Right Click "Libraries", add "JAR/Folder", navigate to "/WEB-INF/lib" of inflated war folder, select all the dependency jars and Click On "Open" of Netbeans Project.

Step 5: Delete WEB-INF of Netbeans Project (Note : Ignore Warning/Error).

Step 6: Delete META-INF of the inflated folder.

Step 7: Copy the remaining content ("/WEB-INF/classes" and "/WEB-INF/lib") of the inflated folder to "Web Pages" of Netbeans Project.

Step 8: Open the following ports in the firewall TCP/843,TCP/1935,TCP/5229,TCP/5080

Step 9: Run the project

Step 10: Deployable war file "red.war" is created in the Netbeans Project Folder(../NetBeansProjects/red5/dist/)

As I am facing errors, I request you to contribute in creating new version(1.0, 1.0.1, 1.02) war deployments  using new version netbeans, jdk for new version glassfish server(3.x).

Arumugam A.V